# Trouble finding the volume using the shell method

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

A region is bounded by the line $y=3x+4$ and the parabola $y=x^2$ and is rotated about the line $x=4$.

First I found the limits of integration by finding the points of intersection. They are $(-1,1)$ and $(4,16)$. I then found the radius from the axis of rotation to be $r=4-x$ and the height to be $h=3x+4-x^2$.

I used the Volume formula $\int_{a}^{b}2\pi (radius)(height)dx$.
$$V=\int_{-1}^{4}2\pi(4-x)(3x+4-x^2)dx$$
$$2\pi \int_{-1}^{4}(x^3-7x^2+8x+16)dx$$

Evaluating this integral I get the volume to be $280\pi-\dfrac{1055}{6}$ but this is no where close to the actual volume. I believe that both my radius and height are right and that the formula is right. I've redid the problem a couple of times and ended up with the same answer, what am I missing here?

Comment: If the line is $x=4$, I'm fairly certain the height should be $x^2-3x-4$? Try doing it like that instead?

Comment: The region is rotated about the line $x=4$, the region is bounded by $y=3x+4$ and $y=x^2$. After drawing this out I think that the line $y=3x+4$ is above the parabola $y=x^2$. So I don't understand why I would try what you suggested.

Comment: You might want to reevaluate your radius

Comment: @StevenN, I'm sorry, I just read that wrong.

Comment: @John I drew the picture out and the radius $4-x$ makes sense to me, how would you find the radius?

Comment: Well, part of the graph is in the negative region, this makes the region radius a bit different. If you translated the graph by 1 unit to the right, your equation would we right, of course including the necessary translations. In other terms, if you find the same thing for $(x-1)^2$ and $3(x-1)+4$ and $x=5$ using radius $5-x$, you would get the right answer.

Comment: I still can't figure out the radius :/, could you explain?

Comment: The setup looks right. The numerical work looks not right.

Comment: By the way, I get $\frac{625}{6}\pi$, but I am error-prone.

Comment: That is the correct answer but I cannot figure out how to get there... I must be doing some algebra wrong.

Comment: If I can do it anybody can. Forget about the $2\pi$ for a while. Integrate, we get $\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{7}{3}x^3+4x^2+16x$. Plug in, watching out for minus sign errors. When I plugged in $4$, I got $\frac{128}{3}$. With $-1$ I got $-\frac{113}{12}$. Integral is $\frac{128}{3}+\frac{113}{12}$. Simplify, multiply by $2\pi$.

Comment: I got the same thing after I integrated but I think I am messing up one of the minus signs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get $2\pi (\frac{255}{4}-\frac{455}{3}+120)$, I think one of the minus signs is throwing me off...

Comment: Plug in $4$. I get $64-\frac{7}{3}\cdot 64+64+64$. Plug in $-1$. I get $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7}{3}+4-16$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In your answer above how did you get $\frac{128}{3}$ by plugging in 4?Isn't it this? $-\frac{7}{3}4^3 = -\frac{448}{3}$

Comment: We get $(64)\left(3-\frac{7}{3}\right)=(64)(2/3)=128/3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I still cannot see why $-\frac{7}{3}x^3$ would turn into $(64)(3-\frac{7}{3})$ when you plug in $4$ :(. Why is my method of evaluating this wrong?

Comment: When we integrate we get $4$ terms, I typed them out earlier, the first was $\frac{x^4}{4}$. You wrote that you got the same thing. Plug in $x=4$. The first term is $\frac{4^4}{4}$, which is $64$. The third and fourth terms also are $64$ at $x=4$.

Comment: This is what I am doing $[(\frac{4^4}{4}-\frac{1}{4})-(\frac{7}{3}(4^3)+\frac{7}{3}(-1)^3)+(4(4)^2-4)+(16(4)+16)]$, I was taught to compute it this way (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 2). Could you explain why this would be incorrect?

Comment: Looks OK, apart from a slightly strange looking thing at the end, maybe it is supposed to be $(16)(4)+16$, in which case it would be right. You may recognize the terms I wrote down earlier, in a different order. You must have added wrong.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I looked back in my notes and found that I WAS supposed to evaluate the four terms for $4$ then subtract it from the value I got when I evaluated at $-1$. I got the correct answer to a similar problem by doing that!

Comment: In principle, either order of evaluation is fine. You are just making a mistake of arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in what you have; the only thing missing is the actual evaluation of the definite integral.  I get $$\displaystyle 2\pi\left[\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{7x^3}{3}+\frac{8x^2}{2}+16x\right]_{-1}^{4}$$

$$\displaystyle 2\pi \left[ \left(64-\frac{7(64)}{3}+64+64\right)- \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7}{3}+\frac{8}{2}-16\right)\right]$$

From there, it's just a matter of simple algebra.  I get $\displaystyle \frac{625\pi}{6}$.

Comment: In fact, this whole question appears to have been brought about because **Kot** had _correctly_ found $ \ 2 \pi \ (\frac{255}{4} - \frac{455}{3} + 60 + 80 ) \ = \ 2 \pi \ (140 - \frac{1055}{12}  ) \ , $ then distributed the factor of 2 over both terms, but _not_ the factor of $ \ \pi \ . $  Otherwise, this would indeed have correctly reduced to $ \ 2 \pi \ (\frac{1680}{12}  - \frac{1055}{12}  ) \ = \ \frac{625 \pi}{6} \ . $